# Cookie not accessible inside REST CFC

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a weird problem. I have a REST service. The folder has its own Application.CFC, which contains an `onRequestStart` method. That method does a small cookie check. If `cookie.someVal` is present, that value is assigned to `Request.someVal`. Otherwise `Request.someVal` is set to 0.  This cookie value is set after user login in main application.

1. Creating a simple cfm page (say test.cfm) & taking the dump after user has logged in shows the correct values of request scope variable.
2. If I call the rest service from the browser directly (it is a GET), and simply return serialized request scope, value comes up nicely.
3. But when I make request with `cfhttp`, from test.cfm, values disappear and the default of 0 is shown.

What is happening here? Why are the cookie values not being identified while making a call with `cfhttp`?

Comment: I needed to pass cookie in cfhttpparam exclusively to make them available to rest api service.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer so this can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies were, in my case domain cookies so browser request will always make them available to my REST service, but when I used to make test call with cfhttp, they are not available. I needed to pass cookie in cfhttpparam exclusively to make them available to rest api service.